# Using Leaflet Marker Dragend?

Tags: leaflet, events, markers, z-index

I am having a problem with leaflet markers. The problem is that when I drag a marker with a lower z-index under another marker with a higher z-index and let it go, it makes another marker. I have a click event that adds a marker to the map when I click it.

This happens in Chrome and Internet Explorer 11.
This does not happend in Firefox.

Another problem I noticed was that when I would drag a marker outside the browser window and relase in Firefox, it would mess up things up.

JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/eaflores/x9JzP/

Comment: Im using Google Chrome, seems like it does not do this in Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: doesn't seem to do this in Firefox here either...

Comment: and i also see it in chrome

Comment: Enrique: you can (and should!) update your question with additional details you have at any time. Just click edit below the question. That will also help to bring it "back to the top" for more attention.

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem with the current jsFiddle and Chrome.  Did you fix it?